# Wrong answer given by a julia code for project euler 29

Tags: julia

I was trying to solve Project Euler Q.29 in julia and I am getting a wring answer.

Here is the problem statement:

```
Consider all integer combinations of ab for 2 ≤ a ≤ 5 and 2 ≤ b ≤ 5:

2^2=4, 2^3=8, 2^4=16, 2^5=32
3^2=9, 3^3=27, 3^4=81, 3^5=243
4^2=16, 4^3=64, 4^4=256, 4^5=1024
5^2=25, 5^3=125, 5^4=625, 5^5=3125
If they are then placed in numerical order, with any repeats removed, we get the following sequence of 15 distinct terms:

4, 8, 9, 16, 25, 27, 32, 64, 81, 125, 243, 256, 625, 1024, 3125

How many distinct terms are in the sequence generated by a^b for 2 ≤ a ≤ 100 and 2 ≤ b ≤ 100?
```

Here is my code, its pure brute force.

```
powers = []

n = 100

for a in collect(2:n)
    for b in collect(2:n)
        append!(powers,a^b)        
    end
end

length(unique(powers))
```

The correct answer is **9183** but I am getting **6143** as the answer.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Note that there is no reason to use `collect` on the ranges in the `for`-loop. `collect` will cause memory allocations which is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much, Fredrik. Actually, I used `collect` to test out with a small number and just copy-pasted it and forgot to remove it. But, thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're suffering from integer overflow - see the manual [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#Overflow-behavior-1):

```
julia> 2^62
4611686018427387904

julia> 2^63
-9223372036854775808
```

You can overcome the issue by using `BigIntegers` like so:

```
powers = []

n = 100

for a in collect(2:n)
    for b in collect(2:n)
        # note the `big()` here
        append!(powers,big(a)^b)        
    end
end

length(unique(powers))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nils. I have some more questions. How do you know when are we supposed to use big and why is the big needed only for a and not for b or for a^b?

Comment: See the manual - it tells you that the largest integer representable as an Int64 is 2^63-1, so for anything larger you want BigIntegers. Here you only need to wrap `a` in `big()` because exponentiation of a big integer by a regular integer is defined as `^(x::BigInt , y::Integer) = bigint_pow(x, y)` (you can do `@which big(2)^63` at the REPL to see where the function you're calling is defined and `@edit big(2)^63` to inspect the source code)